# Geometry based sum

Tags: geometry

Suppose $A_1A_2...A_{20}$  is a $20$-sided polygon. How many non-isosceles(scalene) triangles can be formed whose vertices are among the vertices of the polygon but whose sides are not the sides of the polygon?

Comment: I would first calculate how many you don't want and subtract that from the total (do you think inclusion-exclusion applies?). So, how many triangles DO share sides with the polygons? How many triangles are isosceles? How many both share a side and are isosceles? How many triangles total can be made?

Answer (score 0):

Easily done by inclusion-exclusion. The number of triangles having their vertices among the vertices of the $20$-agon, but with their sides out of the sides of the $20$-agon, equals the number of ways for choosing $3$ non-adjacent people among $20$ people seated around a circular table. By [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), this is $\binom{17}{3}$. It just remains to count the number of isosceles triangles among the previous ones. There are no equilateral triangles since $3\nmid 20$, and each vertex of the $20$-agon is the apex of $8$ isosceles triangles among the previous ones. It follows that the answer is given by
$$ \binom{17}{3}-20\cdot 8 = \color{red}{520}.$$